EF Core 8: how to assign existing entity references to deserialized list
I'm building a Blazor Wasm web app with ASP.NET Core 8 and EF Core 8.
I have the following setup:
public class EventRole
{
    // Composite key
    public long EventId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    // Backwards reference
    [ForeignKey(nameof(EventId))]
    public Event? Event { get; set; }
}

public class EventParticipant
{
    // Composite key
    public long EventId { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    // Content
    public ICollection<EventRole> Roles { get; set; } = new HashSet<EventRole>();

    [ForeignKey(nameof(EventId))]
    public Event? Event { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public User? User { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<EventParticipant> Participants { get; set; } = new HashSet<EventParticipant>();
    public ICollection<EventRole> Roles { get; set; } = new HashSet<EventRole>();
}

So in my context, I setup the following keys:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Primary keys
    modelBuilder.Entity<EventParticipant>()
                .HasKey(p => new { p.EventId, p.UserId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<EventRole>()
                .HasKey(r => new { r.EventId, r.Name });

    // modelBuilder.Entity<EventParticipantRole>().HasKey(pr => new { pr.EventId, pr.UserId, pr.RoleName });

    // AutoInclude properties
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .Navigation(e => e.Participants).AutoInclude();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
                .Navigation(e => e.Roles).AutoInclude();

    modelBuilder.Entity<EventParticipant>()
                .Navigation(p => p.User).AutoInclude();
    modelBuilder.Entity<EventParticipant>()
                .Navigation(p => p.Roles).AutoInclude();
}

In my Blazor app (client side), I wrote the following code:
Event ev = new Event();

EventParticipant participant = new EventParticipant()
{
    User = user;
}

EventRole role = new EventRole
{
    Name = "Organisation"
}

EventRole role2 = new EventRole
{
    Name = "BudgetControl"
}

participant.Roles.Add(role);
participant.Roles.Add(role2);
ev.Roles.Add(role);
ev.Roles.Add(role2);
ev.Participants.Add(participant);

await Http.PostAsJsonAsync<Event>("api/Events", ev);

The EventsController has the default scaffolded PostEvent method with:
_context.Events.Add(@event);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetEvent), new { id = @event.Id }, @event);

Now when running the above code I get the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The value of 'EventRole.EventId' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is not known.

Especially due to the last part of the error I have the feeling that my relations are just not well chosen. However I see that this error happens due to the deserialization of the json. After deserializing, EF does not know whether the roles within the participants are new roles or the same roles as within the event.
So my question is: how can I tell EF Core that the deserialized objects of roles within the participants are the same as the ones in the event and so assigns the same entity reference (and EventId) to the participant roles? Do I need to change my data model for this?
In case it is important: for testing purposes I'm currently using an in-memory database.

You cannot tell EF Core to use such object in the right way, you have to correct deserialised object. Anyway, why you are doing this on the client side?

What do you mean? Assigning the Roles to the Event? And the participant? That's what the user is meant to decide. Or are you anticipating to do a post for the event and seperate POST requests for adding the roles to event and participant?

I mean that deserialzied object is useless for EF Core. Desrialize object and create new for EF Core, which has references. Use surrogate keys to find which objects are the same to fixup references.
